# Meteor How to invoke a function when subscription is ready

Tags: meteor

A Meteor client code needs to invoke a function `openNewTab(age);` when the subscription is ready since the mongodb document supplies the parameters to that function `age`. I have lost count of how many things I tried. Who can it be done? thx

```js
    //client/main.js
    Meteor.startup(function () {
      Tracker.autorun(function () {
        Meteor.subscribe('myCol', Session.get('age'));
      });
    });

//client/lib.js

Template.footer.events({
  'click #submit': (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    lib.usageEntry({taskSelected: taskSelected});
  }
});
const lib = {
  'usageEntry': function (Obj) {
    // do stuff
    lib[Obj.taskSelected]();  // task1
  },
  'task1': function () {
    let age = document.getElementsByClassName('age')[0].text()
    Session.set('age', age);  // so the reactive subscription works
    openNewTab(age);  //<=== how can this wait till subscription is ready?
  }
}


    //server
    Meteor.publish('myCol', function (age) {
      if (!this.userId || Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId}).profile.notOk) return;
      if (Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId}).profile.hasOwnProperty('notPaid')) return;
      let matcher = new RegExp('[0-9]{1,3}', "gi");
      if (matcher.test(age)) {
        return myCol.find({age: age}, {
          fields: {
            propName: true,
          }, limit: 1
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually provide a callback to the `subscribe` function that will execute once the subscription is done.

e.g.

```
const HomeStuffCollection = new Mongo.Collection('homeStuff')

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  const doSomething = (data) => { /* do stuff */ }

  Template.home.onCreated(function() {
    this.subscribe('homeStuff', () => {
      doSomething(HomeStuffCollection.find().fetch())
    })
  })
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('homeStuff', function() {
    return HomeStuffCollection.find()
  })
}
```

Documentation: https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe